# Getting typeof to work with bitfields and literally passed types simultaneously

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, built-in

So, I can check whether two types are compatible by using this:

```
__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), typeof(y))
```

This will work whether `x` and `y` are variables or the types themselves.
To get typeof to work with a bitfield, we would need to use `typeof(+(x))` and `typeof(+(y))`.
Except `typeof(+(int))`, for example, is not valid syntax.
So, is there a way to check whether `x` and `y` can be promoted? I was thinking `__builtin_choose_expr` could help but couldn't come up with anything useful. I want something that would work in every case with a single macro.

I've also noticed `typeof((int) + 1)` works for both situations, but I'm not sure why. It also unfortunately errors with arrays when passed literally, such as `typeof((int[]) + 1)`. I'm also unsure if this is changing the type somehow that could cause incorrect outputs.

Here is a demo that shows my setup with each variation and their errors:

```
#define TypesCompatible_1(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))
#define TypesCompatible_2(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(+(a)), typeof(+(b)))
#define TypesCompatible_3(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof((a) + 1), typeof((b) + 1))


int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        int a : 4;
        int b : 4;
        int c : 4;
    } bitfield;
    
    bitfield z;
    
    int x, y;
    
    int a[5], b[5];
    float c;
    
    // 1: Standard
    
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(x, y));            // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(int, y));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(x, int));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(int, int));        // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(a, b));            // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(a, c));            // -> 0
        
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(z.a, y));       // -> error: ‘typeof’ applied to a bit-field
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_1(a, z.b));       // -> error: ‘typeof’ applied to a bit-field
        
        printf("%d\n\n", TypesCompatible_1(int[], int[]));  // -> 1
    
    
    // 2: Type Promoted
    
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(x, y));            // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(z.a, y));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(x, z.b));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(z.a, z.b));        // -> 1
        printf("%d\n\n", TypesCompatible_2(z.a, c));        // -> 0
        
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(int, y));       // -> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(x, int));       // -> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(int, int));     // -> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(a, b));         // -> error: wrong type argument to unary plus
        
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_2(int[], int[])); // -> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
        
    // 3: Modified
    
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(x, y));            // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(z.a, y));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(x, z.b));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(z.a, z.b));        // -> 1
        printf("%d\n\n", TypesCompatible_3(z.a, c));        // -> 0
        
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(int, y));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(x, int));          // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(int, int));        // -> 1
        printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(a, b));            // -> 1
        printf("%d\n\n", TypesCompatible_3(a, c));          // -> 0
        
        // printf("%d\n", TypesCompatible_3(int[], int[])); // -> error: cast specifies array type

    return 0;
}
```

*Compiled with gcc 4.9.2*

Comment: Please provide a [mre], even if it does not compile without errors. [Edit] your question for this, and please add the compiler and its version.

Comment: Wouldn't it be like `typeof( myStructName.myFieldName )`, with literally passed types impossible because a bitfield can't exist on its own/outside of a structure?

Comment: `__builtin_choose_expr` can unfortunately not evaluate to a type, only to an expression, so using it inside `__builtin_types_compatible_p` does not work.

Comment: @thebusybee I've added an example that shows how the different variations end up erroring. Hopefully that is adequate to help show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: `typeof((int)+1)` just "happen to accidentally" works, because it's the type of the literal `+1` (unary plus) C-style typecasted to `int`.

Comment: Note that, because of integer promotion, doing what you did (applying unary minus on values) will implicitly **convert bit field types to `int`** as well as **converting types such as `short`** to `int`. Is this desired?

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that. But those two conversions are fine for my purposes.
I do need arrays to work though, so it's not really a good solution.